# Unable to start MiniKube: Stuck on Starting Cluster Components

Tags: minikube

I am new to minikube. I followed the below steps to install minikube on oracle linux 7.5 (kernel 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64)

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

After installing i ran the minikube

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Minikube is falied on

```
    sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
    Starting local Kubernetes v1.12.4 cluster...
    Starting VM...
    Waiting for SSH to be available...
    Detecting the provisioner...
    Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
    Getting VM IP address...
    Moving files into cluster...
    Setting up certs...
    Connecting to cluster...
    Setting up kubeconfig...
    Stopping extra container runtimes...
    Starting cluster components...
E0105 13:00:41.436961   19330 start.go:343] Error starting cluster:  timed out waiting to elevate kube-system RBAC privileges: Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings?timeout=1m0s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings?timeout=1m0s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings?timeout=1m0s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings?timeout=1m0s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Temporary Error: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings?timeout=1m0s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I checked logs also and found that it is stuck in some loop and retrying but i am unable to understand

```
I0105 12:24:24.522907   19330 utils.go:224] > Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!
I0105 12:24:24.522916   19330 utils.go:224] > To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:
I0105 12:24:24.522919   19330 utils.go:224] >   mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
I0105 12:24:24.522925   19330 utils.go:224] >   sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
I0105 12:24:24.522929   19330 utils.go:224] >   sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
I0105 12:24:24.522934   19330 utils.go:224] > You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.
I0105 12:24:24.522944   19330 utils.go:224] > Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
I0105 12:24:24.522950   19330 utils.go:224] >   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/
I0105 12:24:24.522957   19330 utils.go:224] > You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node
I0105 12:24:24.522959   19330 utils.go:224] > as root:
I0105 12:24:24.522972   19330 utils.go:224] >   kubeadm join localhost:8443 --token 5apexw.uv7nfpirz4on2e33 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:6dcf73220b8bc229269bb8c6a350592fe6b0cd068ef8f336163cc5b3a384990e
I0105 12:24:45.792762   19330 utils.go:117] sleeping 500ms
I0105 12:24:46.292883   19330 utils.go:106] retry loop 1
I0105 12:25:07.561761   19330 utils.go:117] sleeping 500ms
I0105 12:25:08.062042   19330 utils.go:106] retry loop 2
I0105 12:25:29.330434   19330 utils.go:117] sleeping 500ms
I0105 12:25:29.830625   19330 utils.go:106] retry loop 3
I0105 12:25:51.096835   19330 utils.go:117] sleeping 500ms
I0105 12:25:51.597099   19330 utils.go:106] retry loop 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you did it in AWS. 
Remove all and recreate from the scratch. Just reproduced and all works fine.

Remove all:

```
minikube delete
rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

My steps from the begging(under root):

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube

sudo yum install docker-engine

systemctl enable docker.service

systemctl start docker.service

minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Result:

> ======================================== Starting local Kubernetes v1.12.4 cluster...
>
> Starting VM...
>
> Getting VM IP address...
>
> Moving files into cluster...
>
> Setting up certs...
>
> Connecting to cluster...
>
> Setting up kubeconfig...
>
> Stopping extra container runtimes...
>
> Starting cluster components...
>
> Verifying kubelet health ...
>
> Verifying apiserver health ...Kubectl is now configured to use the
>   cluster.
>
> ===================
>
> WARNING: IT IS RECOMMENDED NOT TO RUN THE NONE DRIVER ON PERSONAL
>   WORKSTATIONS  The 'none' driver will run an insecure kubernetes
>   apiserver as root that may leave the host vulnerable to CSRF attacks
>
> When using the none driver, the kubectl config and credentials
>   generated will be root owned and will appear in the root home
>   directory. You will need to move the files to the appropriate location
>   and then set the correct permissions.  An example of this is below:
>
> sudo mv /root/.kube $HOME/.kube # this will write over any previous configuration 
>   sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube 
>   sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.kube
>
> sudo mv /root/.minikube $HOME/.minikube # this will write over any previous configuration
>    sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube 
>    sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
>
> This can also be done automatically by setting the env var
>   CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true Loading cached images from config file.
>
> Everything looks great. Please enjoy minikube!

Comment: I tried the exact steps given by you. Now i am getting different error.

Comment: E0107 12:04:11.503188   11460 start.go:343] Error starting cluster:  kubeadm init error

Comment: sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-

Comment: errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 
 running command: : Process exited with status 2

Comment: Also I am not installing it in AWS. I am installing in my desktop machine.

Comment: Weird thing. There are so many issues with this minikube, special when it fails to install for the first time. Look this comment, maybe it will help you: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3022#issuecomment-424145410. And what about forget about minikube, download kubeadm. kubectl binaries and bootstrap you cluster step by step on your own? Here is great article for you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/